# Can I change the default color of a progress bar in LiveCode?

Tags: user-experience, livecode

Is there a way to change the default color of the progress bar to any color
other than green?  For instance, I would like it to be red until it gets to
100% and then it turns green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked on a LiveCode list serve and I'm answering here because others might find it useful.

No it's not possible to do this but it is easy to create a custom progress bar that you can set the color how you like.

Create two graphics. One for the border and one for the bar. Set the colors and graphic effects however you like. Group them and then add the following to the group script:

```
setProp uPercent pPercent -- 0..100
   put the rect of grc "border" of me into tRect
   put round(item 1 of tRect+(item 3 of tRect-item 1 of tRect)*pPercent/100) into item 3 of tRect
   set the rect of grc "bar" of me to tRect
end uPercent
```